# Print selected columns from a file if the row is mentioned in another file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

My first file contains data like:

```
Gene symbol Gene name   Chromosome  Start   End Strand  Otter gene ID   Otter transcript ID Ensembl gene ID Ensembl transcript ID   Gene biotype    Transcript biotype


OR4G4P  olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily G, member 4 pseudogene  1   52473   53312   +   OTTHUMG00000185779  OTTHUMT00000471235  ENSG00000268020 ENST00000606857 unprocessed_pseudogene  unprocessed_pseudogene


OR4G11P olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily G, member 11 pseudogene 1   57598   64116   +   OTTHUMG00000001095  OTTHUMT00000492680  ENSG00000240361 ENST00000642116 transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene  processed_transcript
```

The second file contains just the gene names:

```
Ectopic
OR10J3
OR2C3
OR2W3
OR2T8
OR2T6
```

I want to retrieve specific columns (1, 3, 4 and 5) of the 'genes' from the first file that are also present in the second file.

I used awk command:

```
 awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next}; ($1 in a) {print}' OR.csv ectopic.csv > OR_ect.csv
```

but no file is generated. Being new to this, I am facing quite an issue.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: DId you use the "first  file" and "second file" in the correct order (i.e., is `OR.csv` the "second file", because that's what should be processed by `FNR==NR`)? Also, you use `,` as the field separator, but at least in the example input given, there is no `,` in `OR4G4P  olfactory receptor`, but these look two different fields.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your files datafile.txt (main data) and listfile.txt (gene names).

First extract all the lines from datafile.txt whose name appears in listfile.txt

```
grep -f listfile.txt datafile.txt > temp.txt
```

now use awk to extract the columns you need from temp.txt

```
awk -F, '{print $1,$3,$4,$5}'
```

(and remove the temp.txt file)

You can do away with temp file by piping the grep into awk directly.